# How do I make the Extended WPF Toolkit ColorPicker work?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, color-picker

I would like to be able to use this color picker in my application:

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Documentation

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with .NET 4 installed. I'm coding in C# and WPF (XAML).

What I've done so far:

1. Downloaded and unzipped WPFToolkit.Extended.dll
2. Added a reference to it in Visual Studio (can I verify this somehow?)
3. Added this line to MainWindow.xaml.cs: *using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;*
4. Added the bold line to MainWindow.xaml:

   < Window x:Class="TDDD49Task2.ColorWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           **xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit/"** [...]>
5. Tried to use < xctk:ColorPicker> in MainWindow.xaml (Error message: "*The type 'xctk:ColorPicker' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.*").
6. Googled for a solution, tutorial or example without much success.

Please explain how the Extended WPF Toolkit is used or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its worked for me though but the `namespace` you included is incorrect. `Remove the last  backslash at the end`. It should be -

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

instead of

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit/"
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I still get the same error message. Could you perhaps paste some more (working) XAML code? I also found the toolkit under References in the Solution Explorer, so I know it's there. Did you do anything else after adding the reference?

Comment: Are you getting the error at design time or during compile time? because i am getting the error at design time but when i run the application it works fine.

Answer (score 21):

This error occur also when you don't unblock the assembly.

Below is short instruction to this:

1. Right click on the "WPFToolkit.Extended.dll".
2. Click Unblock in the Security section.

[image]

Comment: It may be well over a year later, but your solution was the one that helped me! So a very belated thanks for your answer.